# Этимология слова коварный

Tags: этимология

Подскажите этимологию слова "коварный"! От какого слова? Что значит?

Comment: В книге С.М. Броневского (1763--1830) "Новейшия географическия и исторические известия о Кавказе" на с. 74 сказано о кабардинцах - "Кабары" - они же "КАВАРЫ". Кавары-каварство (коварство). Возможно, что отсюда пошло это слово.

Answer (score 3):

***Коварный*** — таящий угрозу, хотя внешне дружественный или безопасный. Происходит от др.-русск., ст.-слав. коварьнъ, от *коварь «кузнец»; ср. чешск. kovář «кузнец», в.-луж. kovaŕ и кова́ть. Ср. церк.-слав. ковати зълаıа «замышлять недоброе». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера;

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Интересно, а почему слово "кузнец" преобразовалось в такое негативное понятие?

Comment: *Интересно, а почему слово "кузнец" преобразовалось в такое негативное понятие?*  Так вот же. *Ср. церк.-слав. ковати зълаıа «замышлять недоброе»*

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с Валентином. Хочется только уточнить, откуда появился отрицательный смысл. Слово заимствовано из старославянского, где имело значение не только "тот, кто куёт", но и "искусный, мудрый", а это значение скоро расширилось и приняло вид "хитрый, лукавый", а затем добавилось "предательский". В др.-р. у слова коварство были значения "ум", "тонкость", "замысловатость", "хитрость, лукавство", ему родственно козни.

Answer (score 0):

Ни в одном из славянских языков нет аналогов слову "коварный". В большинстве случаев будет фигурировать "лукавство". "Ковать ковы", связь с кузнецами через "ковачей" и "ковалей" лично мне кажется надуманной. Возможно, куда интереснее и плодотворнее будет найти и проследить связь с англ. "coward" - трус, трусливый. С учётом того, что "ложь и коварство - прибежище глупцов и трусов". )) Интересно, когда в русском языке (хотя бы примерно) появились первые случаи употребления слова "коварный" и в каком контексте они тогда употреблялись.

Comment: Если у вас возник вопрос, то и задавайте его как вопрос.  А в качестве ответа ваш текст никак не годится. К тому же вы сообщаете недостоверные сведенья. 
коварный

кова́рный --------  др.-русск., ст.-слав. коварьнъ. От *коварь "кузнец"; ср. чеш. kovář "кузнец", в.-луж. kovaŕ и кова́ть. Ср. цслав. ковати зълаɪа "замышлять недоброе"; см. Бернекер 1, 593.

Comment: у меня не возникало вопросов, если вы не заметили, в конце предложения я этот знак не поставил. стилистически это не вопрос, а размышление. настаиваю: я не вижу причин считать кузнецов коварными только потому, что они "ковы куют". еще раз повторяю: ни в одном славянском языке нет аналогов "коварству". я призвал только задуматься. и не надо мне подсовывать классические словари. там достаточно много авторитетных нелепиц.

Comment: Добавление по поводу ссылки на чешских коварных кузнецов kovář'ей. Было бы логично допустить и в чешском языке возможность найти отголоски их коварства, ан нет, ничего подобного мы не найдем, коварство - это lstivost. Во всех славянских языках нет прямой, да и косвенной связи тоже не существует между кузнецами, ковалями и коваржами с понятием злого умысла и коварства. нет такой связи и в других языках. Ни смиты, ни шмидты в этих злых умыслах замешаны не были. Поэтому странно, что именно в русском языке появилось это "необъяснимое" слово.

Comment: Мне кажется, что коварство этого слово в том и состоит, что оно трусливо заимствовано. Нет? Не надо напрягаться, господа. Вопрос этот - чисто риторический.

Answer (score 0):

Есть родственное слово *свара* = ссора, брань, злословие, но есть ещё и:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно сделать вывод, что в корне *-ва-* заложена общая для них негативная нота.

При том, что там же в ПЦСС есть слово *свайка* (древне-русская игра), то, сдаётся, не все слова этого корня имеют мрачную окраску. Взять хотя бы мирское — *свадьба*.